# How do I solve the Vanguard hacking mini-game?

Tags: killzone-mercenary

When hacking Vanguard posts in the game, you are presented with this screen
[image: Vanguard hacking minigame]

How do you get past this mini-game? What are you supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple but not very intuitive.

You have to pick the two "Cipher Keys" that make up the one in the middle, in the example above, these are keys C & F. What isn't very clear is ***how*** you pick them. **You need to tap one of the keys, tap the middle symbol, then tap the other key and again the middle symbol.**